# Custom Button does not react on IsMouseOver

Tags: wpf, image, templates, button

I've created control IconButton (derives from Button) to show big icon in center of my button. Everything seems to works fine but triggers. The background should change when mouse is over my control.

code behind:

```
public class IconButton : System.Windows.Controls.Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Image", typeof(System.Windows.Media.ImageSource), typeof(IconButton));

    public System.Windows.Media.ImageSource Image
    {
        get
        {
            return (System.Windows.Media.ImageSource)GetValue(ImageProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ImageProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public IconButton()
    {
        SetResourceReference(StyleProperty, "IconsStyle");
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="IconsStyle" TargetType="local:IconButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:IconButton">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                        CornerRadius="10" 
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"  
                        MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxHeight}"
                        MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}" 
                        MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}" 
                        MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}" 
                        Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" 
                        Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" 
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,2">
                            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Green"/>
                            <GradientStop Offset="2" Color="White"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            Source="{TemplateBinding Image}"/>
                        <ContentControl 
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            Grid.Row="1" 
                            Padding="0" 
                            FontSize="12" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                            Background="Transparent"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <GradientStop Offset="-1" Color="Green"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="White"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="2" Color="Green"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

What's wrong with that code? Why background is not changing when I'm moving mouse over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Background` property that you are setting in the `IsMouseOver` Trigger is never used.

You should modify the Style like shown below. It adds a

```
Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
```

assignment to the Border control and defines the default Background by a Style Setter.

```
<Style x:Key="IconsStyle" TargetType="local:IconButton">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,2">
                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Green"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="2" Color="White"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:IconButton">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" ... >
                    ...
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <GradientStop Offset="-1" Color="Green"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="White"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="2" Color="Green"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the **ContentControl** a name and try setting the property and element name like this. This should fix your issue.

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ContentControl1"
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
    Grid.Row="1" 
    Padding="0" 
    FontSize="12" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
    Background="Transparent"/>
</Grid>
</Border>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
<Setter TargetName="ContentControl1" Property="Background" >
    <Setter.Value>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Offset="-1" Color="Green"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="White"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="2" Color="Green"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```